# CSS Submenu item bound position to menus parent element size

Tags: html, css

I created a CSS menu which has menu items and submenu items. These submenu items are actually big divs which gets shown when the user hovers the menu item.

They work pretty well but I have one problem:

If the submenu is wider than the whole menu, it overflows and may break the pages width in the worst case.

When the submenu reaches the right side of the menu, it should "stick" at `right:0px`.

Is there any possibility to limit the position of an element to it's grandparental's width? Resp. is there a way to achieve my goal in pure CSS? I don't really want to use JavaScript for that.

This is the HTML structure and an excerpt of the important CSS:

```
.navi {
    height:60px;
    width:350px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#DEDEDE;
}
.navi ul {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:50px;
}
.navi ul li {
    float:left;
    height:60px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
}
.navi ul li a {
    height:100%;
    line-height:60px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.navi ul li:hover .submenu {
    display:block;
}
.navi ul li .submenu {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#F3F3F3;
}

<div class="navi">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>a navigation link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>a navigation link</a>
            <div class="submenu">
                <!-- content -->
            </div>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </li>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/julian_weinert/xB5UK/) showing my menu.

Comment: You can just put your .submenu a width of 100% (100% of parent element), but I don't know if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/xB5UK/2/

Comment: No and no. I want the submenu to be like 600px wide (fixed). @JoshPowell: See my updated fiddle again. I inserted a second submenu. That should (of course) be underneath the first menu item and so on

Comment: Something around the lines of this? http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/xB5UK/4/

Comment: Nope. Now there are both 100% wide. See my original fiddle again. Exactly like this except that the second items submenu should stick to the right, because it **WOULD** overflow.

Comment: Okay finally, like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/xB5UK/5/ or this? http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/xB5UK/6/

Comment: You changed the width of the menu elements. But their width should depend on the content. The solution shouldn't change the menu items itself... I don't think there's a solution for that... :(